# How can i Print (via a printer),data that is split into different pages, without having the print dialog box pop up many times?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a program in PHP that makes score sheets for students after their marks have been keyed in and then generates their score sheets. I need to print all the score sheets for each student. 
I tried using `window.print()//in javascript`.
This means i have to view the score sheet for each student and print it one by one. This would be a lot of work, case i have like 500 students. Is there a way i can have one button that when pressed gives the print dialog box once and then prints all the score sheets without popping up the dialog each time a new score sheet is being printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a single web page which contains all of the score sheets, and print that!

You can use the `page-break` family of CSS properties (e.g, `page-break-before: always`) to ensure that the score sheets are printed on separate pages.

Comment: Say i have 500 scoresheets will it automatically identify on the print dialog that i am printing from page 1 to 500?

Comment: Depends on the browser. Some, like Chrome, will tell you how many pages you're about to print. Others won't.